# Laravel, unable to save with date in future (end date)

Tags: php, laravel

My website has a function, Create a Task, so users may add ENDDate of task.

E.g I have added the enddate 03.03.2018, but when task is saved, i see in blade view (frontendt), that enddate is -> 16.02

so, script just ignoring my enddate and save all the time enddate +7 days

here is part of my **taskcontroller**

```
if ($request->input('select_time') == 1) {
//            $tz = $this->getTimeZoneFromIpAddress();
//            $date = Carbon::now()->tz($tz);
            // echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");

            $created = new \Carbon\Carbon($taskModel->dateAndTimeTodatetime($request));
//            $created = date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");

            if ($created->isPast()) 
                return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(\Lang::get('alerts.task.time'))->withInput();
        }
```

**here is blade view of creation task (part where user choosing date + hours)**

```
<div class="sel_date_block_right list_time" @if(old('select_time') != 1) style="display: none" @endif>
                        <div class="sel_date_block_dt">
                            <div class="">
                                {!! Form::text('date', $task ? $task->getTaskFinalDate('d.m.Y') : (old('date') ?: ''), array('min'=> date('Y-m-d'),'class'=>'')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sel_date_block_dt">
                            <div class="">
                                {!! Form::text('time', $task ? $task->getTaskFinalDate('H:i') : (old('time')?:''), array('min'=>date('H:i'),'class'=>'')) !!}
                            </div>
```

and here is a blade view of a task

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col text-r">
                                <p><strong>@lang('static.lasttime')</strong></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <p>{!! $task->getTaskFinalDate('d.m.y  <span class="cl_gray">H:i</span>') !!}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I spend more then 3 days, figuring out what is a rpoblem.
 :(

Tnx in advance

Comment: Have you checked if the database was updated with `"future"` date?

Comment: u mean after I add task? every task enddate is 16 (+7 days)

Comment: Your guidelines are not clear to me, I can't seem to figure out what you mean when you say your `enddate is 03.03.2018 but when task is saved end date is 16.02, so, script just ignoring my enddate and save all the time enddate +7 days`. How is 03.03 + 7 days = 16.02? Isn't it supposed to be 10.03?

Comment: Oh you meant the date you want to save is 03.03 but it saves 16.02, so it substracts 7 days, not add?

Comment: Yes ;) all the time is ignoring my enddate, which was set (eg 03.3) and everytime, it setting up + 7 days only

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is in this piece of code `$created = new \Carbon\Carbon($taskModel->dateAndTimeTodatetime($request));`, because we don't know what `$taskModel` is and we don't know what `dateAndTimetodatetime` method does. You are probably creating the date badly.

Based on my asumptions, possible solution is  to get a correct date in `Carbon` with `createFromFormat` function which instantiates a `Carbon` instance from a string.

```
$carbonDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $request->get('date').' '.$request->get('time'));
```

Now you can call other methods documented in their [official docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-introduction)

Comment: i have in models -> Task.php

 public function dateAndTimeTodatetime(Request $request) {
        $final_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $date = $request->input('date');
        $time = $request->input('time');

        if ($date && $time) {
            $final_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', $date . ' ' . $time)->toDateTimeString();
        }

        return $final_date;
    }
it should work :(

Comment: Try and dump that date and date from my example above, and paste the results here

Comment: after DD evertthing is OK, don't know why in DB it saved in wrong way

Comment: I don't see from the above code in your question where are you even saving the model, could you post that part?